Intuition for the Picard group of cuspidal curve
I understand that for $k$ a field of characteristic $0$, the (affine) cuspidal cubic has Picard group $k^+$. For the nodal cubic, we get $k^*$. I see intuitively why we get $k^*$ for the nodal cubic: the fiber of any line bundle over the node is glued from two fibers on the affine line (its normalization) between which the isomorphisms are given by $\operatorname{GL}_1(k)\cong k^*$. I don't, however, have any geometric intuition for why $k^+$ would be the Picard group of the cuspidal cubic. Perhaps I don't have a good enough grasp on what the normalization map $\mathbb{A}_k^1\longrightarrow\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ really "looks like" (I can write it down, but I can't visualize it like I can for the nodal cubic). Is there intuition to be obtained here?
As for motivation, this question is a precursor to another question I'll probably ask later. In particular, I'm interested in the extent to which the Picard group can detect specific types of singularities (or more precisely, the extent to which the Picard group can detect if a scheme is seminormal).

For some rough intuition: the normalization map for the cuspidal cubic is doing something like gluing two infinitesimally close points. Or, slightly more precisely, it is collapsing a first order neighborhood to a point. The Picard group can be understood in terms of the descent data for this identification similarly to the nodal case.

Since you're mentioning seminormalization, perhaps you're already aware of this, but a theorem of Traverso and Swan shows that a ring $A$ is seminormal if and only if the natural homomorphism $\mathrm{Pic}(A) \to \mathrm{Pic}(A[t])$ is an isomorphism. (I.e., the Picard group is homotopy-invariant.)

@PeterHaine I have seen this result! I'm glad that you commented because my interest in this comes from some work in trying to generalize Voevodsky's anabelian paper. He says it suffices for reconstruction that there are no $k^+$'s in $Pic(X)$. It looks like $k^+$'s in $Pic(X)$ detect a lack of seminormality: you get them for $y^2-x^d$ ($d\geq3$), plane triple point, etc. So he might only need seminormality (the best hope ofc). But it's likely too naive to ask that $Pic(A)$ htpy-invar implies $k^+\not\leq Pic(A)$ (for one, the $k^+$ criterion looks stronger than necessary). Any thoughts?

@ThighHighCrocs Interesting! Actually, Magnus Carlson, Sebastian Wolf, and I are currently finishing up a paper where we generalize Voevodsky's result. Indeed, we prove reconstruction for seminormal schemes of finite type over a finitely generated field of characteristic 0. (Seminormality is the optimal assumption in this case.) We also prove results in positive characteristic. If you e-mail me, we'd be very happy to arrange to talk about this!

The ring $k[x , y]/(y^2 - x^3) \cong k[t^2 , t^3]$ is Noetherian so we have an fpqc cover of the cuspidal cubic by the open $U$ away from the origin and the formal disk $D$ at the origin. Concretely, these correspond to the algebras $k[t^2 , t^3][1 / t^2] \cong k[t , 1 / t]$ and $k[[t^2 , t^3]]$. A line bundle $L$ on the cubic is equivalent to the data of a pair of line bundles $M$ on $U$ and $N$ on $D$ together with an isomorphism $\varphi$ on the intersection $D^\circ$ corresponding to the field $k[[t^2 , t^3]][1/t^2] \cong k((t))$. Since $U \cong \mathbb{G}_m$ and $k[[t^2 , t^3]]$ is local, both have trivial Picard groups. Given trivializations of $M , N$ the line bundle $L$ is determined by an element of $k((t))^\times$. Modding out by the choice of trivializations shows that the Picard group of the cuspidal cubic is the double coset
$$
k[[t^2 , t^3]]^\times \backslash k((t))^\times / k[t , 1 / t]^\times 
\cong 
\left(k^\times + t^2 k[[t]] \right)\backslash \left( 
t^\mathbb{Z}(k^\times + t k[[t]]) \right) / k^\times t^\mathbb{Z}
\cong \{1 + c t \text{ mod }t^2 \,\vert\, c \in k\} \cong k^+
$$
Concretely, the line bundle $L(c)$ corresponding $c \in k$ is the $k[t^2 , t^3]$ submodule of $k(t)$ generated by $1 + c t , t^2 $. The trivial case is $c = 0$. Now let $c \neq 0$. Then we have restrictions
$$
L(c)_D = \langle 1 + c t \rangle
$$
$$
L(c)_U = \langle 1 \rangle
$$
where $1 + ct$ is a basis vector on $D$ because we have $t^2 = \left(\sum_{n \geq 0} (-c)^n t^{n + 2}\right) (1 + c t) $.
So the transition map on $D^\circ$ is given by mutiplying $1 + c t$.
Credits also @Kenny Lau for working this out with me!
